# A typo on the generator of the example in the paper of De Masi Ferrari and Lebowitz1986

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Context: At page 603 of the paper ["Reaction-Diffusion equations for Interacting Particle Systems"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01011311) from De Masi Ferrari and Lebowitz one reads:

[image]

Here, instead of $\frac{\epsilon^{-2}}{2}$ shouldn't it be $\epsilon^{-2}$?

We remember the definition:
[image]

and since we are working on $\Bbb{Z}$, the transition involving $x$ and $x+1$ can occur when a particle at $x$ jumps to  $x+1$  or when a particle at $x + 1$ jumps to $x$. Therefore we should get

$$L_\epsilon f(\sigma) = \sum_x \bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i 1_{A_i} [f(\sigma^x) - f(\sigma)] + \epsilon^{-2}[f(\sigma^{x,x+1}) - f(\sigma)]\bigg\} $$

Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You forgot about the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the very definition of $L_E$, as far as I can see.

Comment: I think I didn't, see if I had forgottem, according to my reasoning I would find $L_\epsilon f(\sigma) = \sum_x \bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i 1_{A_i} [f(\sigma^x) - f(\sigma)] + 2\epsilon^{-2}[f(\sigma^{x,x+1}) - f(\sigma)]\bigg\}$ Since one exchange is from the left, and one is from the right...